# ionic 2 infinite scroll error

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm trying to do infinite scroll in ionic2 but whenever the page loads i get this error `Cannot read property 'complete' of undefined`

HTML

```
<ion-content>

 <ion-list>
   <ion-item *ngFor="let item of posts" (click)="passurl($event,item)">
     <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
     </ion-item>
 </ion-list>

 <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="ionViewDidLoad($event)">
   <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
 </ion-infinite-scroll>

</ion-content>
```

JS

```
ionViewDidLoad(infiniteScroll){
    let loader = this.LoadingController.create({
    content: 'Please Wait'
    });
    loader.present().then(()=>{
      this.http.get('http://mynewweb/templates/messages/titles.php?church_id='+ this.church_id+'&msg_type='+this.NavParams.data.id+ "&page="+this.page).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data =>{
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            setTimeout(() => {
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
              this.numofposts = data.length;
            this.posts.push(data[i]);
             }
        infiniteScroll.complete();
          }, 500);
        });
     this.page=this.page+1;
    loader.dismiss();
    });

  }
```

i followed the documentation on the ionic2 framework from their website. any help with this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the `ionViewDidLoad` hook as the target of the [InfiniteScroll](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/). You can put the same logic in a different method, like this:

```
<ion-infinite-scroll *ngIf="!hideInfinite" (ionInfinite)="loadData($event)">
  <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

And in the component code:

```
public hideInfinite: boolean;

public loadData(infiniteScroll?: any): void {
    let loader = this.LoadingController.create({
        content: 'Please Wait'
    });

    loader.present().then(()=>{

        this.http.get('http://mynewweb/templates/messages/titles.php?church_id='+ this.church_id+'&msg_type='+this.NavParams.data.id+ "&page="+this.page).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

                if(!data || !data[0]) {
                    // Hide the infiniteScroll if there's no more data
                    this.hideInfinite = true;
                }

                setTimeout(() => {
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                        this.numofposts = data.length;
                        this.posts.push(data[i]);
                    }

                    // Check if it's not null/undefined before calling the complete method
                    if(infiniteScroll) {
                        infiniteScroll.complete();
                    }

                }, 500);
            });

        this.page=this.page+1;
        loader.dismiss();
    });

}
```

If you want to use the same logic in the `ionViewDidLoad` lifecycle hook, you could call the same method:

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
  // You can now call the method without sending anything, 
  // since in the code we check if the infiniteScroll is defined 
  // before using its methods
  this.loadData();
}
```

Comment: its working but how can i set the infinite scroll to stop when data returns false, cos when there is no data again and i scroll still the loader shows up and sends request to the api

Comment: I've added a new property `hideInfinite` in the page, and a check in the html code `...*ngIf="!hideInfinite"...`. You'd need to set that property to true when there's no more data (I've also added that in the code).

Comment: its still doing the same thing

Comment: what does the api return when there's no more data?

Comment: it returns [false]

Comment: That's an array with a false value inside?

Comment: Yes please its an array with a false value inside

Comment: I've edited the check like this: `if(!data || !data[0]) { this.hideInfinite = true; }`. Please take a look at the edited answer and let me know if it works.

Comment: please sorry for the late reply but it still didn't work i managed to solve it with the script with my answer

Comment: So the response was not an array with false value inside... Please try to explain better the scenario the next time because it's quite hard to try to solve the issue if there's wrong information in the comments...

Answer (score 0):

old ionic need to write like this

`$event.state = "closed";`

new version ionic need to write like this

`infiniteScrollEvent.complete();`

(or)

`infiniteScrollEvent.target.complete();`

Answer (score 0):

ionViewDidLoad(infiniteScroll) {

```
this.http.get('http://mynewweb/templates/messages/titles.php?church_id=' + this.church_id + '&msg_type=' + this.NavParams.data.id + "&page=" + this.page).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

  if (infiniteScroll) {
    infiniteScroll.complete();
  }

});
this.page = this.page + 1;
```

}

Comment: ionViewDidLoad(infiniteScroll) {

    this.http.get('http://mynewweb/templates/messages/titles.php?church_id=' + this.church_id + '&msg_type=' + this.NavParams.data.id + "&page=" + this.page).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

      if (infiniteScroll) {
        infiniteScroll.complete();
      }

    });
    this.page = this.page + 1;

  }

Comment: use this code in your application
 if (infiniteScroll) {
  Infinitescroll.target.complete();
  }


this.code ionic 4

Answer (score -1):

```
public play=true;
  public loadData(infiniteScroll?: any): void {
    let loader = this.LoadingController.create({
        content: 'Please Wait'
    });

    loader.present().then(()=>{

        this.http.get('http://mynewweb/templates/messages/titles.php?church_id='+ this.church_id+'&msg_type='+this.NavParams.data.id+ "&page="+this.page).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
            data => {
              this.numofposts=this.numofposts+data.length;
              this.itemsdisplayed = this.itemsdisplayed + 10;

                if(this.itemsdisplayed > this.numofposts) {
                    // Hide the infiniteScroll if there's no more data
                    this.play = false;
                }

                setTimeout(() => {
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                        this.numofposts = data.length;
                        this.posts.push(data[i]);
                    }

                    // Check if it's not null/undefined before calling the complete method
                    if(infiniteScroll) {
                        infiniteScroll.complete();
                    }

                }, 500);
            });

        this.page=this.page+1;
        loader.dismiss();
    });

}
```

HTML

```
<ion-infinite-scroll *ngIf="play" (ionInfinite)="loadData($event)">
  <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```